# Running Electron with Linux on Windows

Tags: windows, electron, windows-subsystem-for-linux, electron-forge

I'm trying to get an electron forge app running on my Windows 10 machine via Linux on windows (using the new built-in windows bash functionality).

When running `electron-forge start` I am getting back the error message:

```
[1484:1126/222326.466455:FATAL:setuid_sandbox_host.cc(157)] The SUID sandbox helper binary was found, but is not configured correctly. Rather than run without sandboxing I'm aborting now. You need to make sure that /mnt/c/.../node_modules/electron/dist/chrome-sandbox is owned by root and has mode 4755.
```

From some searching, this [thread on the electron Github](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/17972#issuecomment-516957971) makes it pretty clear that this is somewhat by design and the way to get around it is to run chmod as a root user post-installing all of the dependencies.

I attempted to do this and the command looked like it had worked (no error on running the chmod to 4755), but that didn't fix running `electron-forge start` - I still got the same error message. I looked into that a bit and it seems that this has to do with what files the linux subsystem are allowed to control permissions for per [this Microsoft thread](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/810).

Is there some other trick to getting electron forge to work with bash on Windows?

Answer (score 0):

I found that running the `electron-forge init` from Windows powershell into a native Windows directory allowed me to subsequently use `npm start` in `my-app` (for example) in WSL. So ultimately what I ran was

```
powershell npx create-electron-app my-app
```

(I have `alias powershell="/mnt/c/windows/system32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/powershell.exe"` in my .bashrc file)